# Dedekind sums when h,k are from Fibonacci sequence

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

This is definition of dedekind sums : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindSum.html

Let {u(n)} be fibonacci sequence such that u(1)=u(2)=1 and u(n+1) = u(n)+u(n-1). If h=u(2n) and k=u(2n+1) then prove that s(h,k)=0.

according to defination of s(h,k) i simplified s(h,k) but I am having problem in how to simplify $\sum_{r=1}^{u(2n+1)-1} [ \frac{u(2n) r} {u(2n+1)}]$. Here [  ] is greatest integer function. Rest of summatiuons  I have simplified the rest but in this I am not sure what property of fibonacci sequence should ve used.

Thaks for any help

Comment: Please give references for the proposition that should be shown. It would be also nice to post using mathjax, it is easy and nice for the reader: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference - Could you please edit the question? Then please show explicitly the steps in your try, the present is too concise. (Since finally, a laconic answer with a general hint would not be accepted, i'm afraid...)

Comment: @dan_fulea The question is part of assignments in number thory for my course